# Outlook 2007 support for html based email using Position style

Tags: html, outlook-2007

I am generating an email in HTML format that contains the DIV tag as follows:

```
<div style="position: absolute; left: 10px; top: 50px;">
```

Outlook 2007 is not able to display the email properly. It is ignoring various styles.

I have gone through [this](http://www.sitepoint.com/blogs/2007/01/10/microsoft-breaks-html-email-rendering-in-outlook/#) article.


I knew that there is a feature in Outlook 2007 to view the Email in Browser. It displays the email properly in the browser.


Is there any way to display the HTML based email that contains complex HTML style or tags in Outlook 2007?

Answer (score 0):

no - outlook 2007 html rendering is worse then the previous version of outlook. Basically you need to code the email like you coded a website in the late 90's.